# Google Sheets SetValue starting on second row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets to track the stats of alliances within a web based game. To get these stats, I used the game's API to find alliances, and get values such as score, members, cities and other. These are stored in a sheet like so:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/raO4f.png

I need to log or print these values into cells at the end of each day. There needs to be a running record for each alliance. To do this, I have made a new sheet with dates in column A. I have followed advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255298/how-can-i-record-the-contents-of-a-google-sheets-cell-at-the-end-of-each-day) stackoverflow post. I modified the code like so:

```
function scorekeeper(){
  var Militaries = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Militaries");
  var Rose = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Rose");
  var members = Militaries.getRange("B2").getValue(); // we want to store this
  var score = Militaries.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var cities = Militaries.getRange("D2").getValue();
  var soldiers = Militaries.getRange("E2").getValue();
  var tanks = Militaries.getRange("F2").getValue();
  var aircraft = Militaries.getRange("G2").getValue();
  var ships = Militaries.getRange("H2").getValue();
  var missiles = Militaries.getRange("I2").getValue();
  var nukes = Militaries.getRange("J2").getValue();
  var treasures = Militaries.getRange("L2").getValue();

  var row_members = Rose.getRange("B2").getValue(); // this is our row
  var row_score = Rose.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var row_cities = Rose.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var row_soldiers = Rose.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var row_tanks = Rose.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var row_aircraft = Rose.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var row_ships = Rose.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var row_missiles = Rose.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var row_nukes = Rose.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var row_treasures = Rose.getRange("B2").getValue();

  Rose.getRange(row_members, 3).setValue(members);
  Rose.getRange(row_score, 4).setValue(score);
  Rose.getRange(row_cities, 5).setValue(cities);
  Rose.getRange(row_soldiers, 6).setValue(soldiers);
  Rose.getRange(row_tanks, 7).setValue(tanks);
  Rose.getRange(row_aircraft, 8).setValue(aircraft);
  Rose.getRange(row_ships, 9).setValue(ships);
  Rose.getRange(row_missiles, 10).setValue(missiles);
  Rose.getRange(row_nukes, 11).setValue(nukes);
  Rose.getRange(row_treasures, 12).setValue(treasures);
}
```

This sets variables to store, getting values from the sheet in the screenshot, and pastes or prints them based on variables I've defined as a location to print. However, when I run this script the result appears like so:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7x5c.png

I would like to get the values to start on the second row, and all future records to appear underneath that. How can I do this?
And also, will this code log vlaues each day? I have followed Niccolo's post, but I would like to be sure that these values will log each day.

Sorry if this is a frequent repost, I took a look around for a while before asking and couldn't find the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask], more specifically [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find the problem. It wasn't with the script, it was with the MATCH formula. I didn't understand its use, and assumed it needed to be repeated in every row, but it acts as a row identifier to tell the script which row to set values to.