# How to add count (count+1) in cell B1 if A1 criterion is matched on a daily base for Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

A1: `=IF(ABS(D2)>6, "hi", "no")`

what should be the formula to accumulate the COUNT in cell B1 on a daily base?

I had tried B1: `=IF(A1="hi", COUNTIF(A1,"hi"),"")` but seems not what I need.

**note:** related to this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25292163/5632629

Answer (score 1):

> There are complicated ways which use Scripts to perform such a task.
>   Those ways are much efficient and robust.

**Important Note! This works only if the only changing variable is A1**

The solution I came up with is a quick fix.

You need to first enable Iterative Calculation and set the Max iteration value to `1`.

> File > Spreadsheet Settings > Calculations

Then you can use `=IF(A1 ="hi", SUM(B1,1),SUM(B1,0))` at `B1`.

[Check the Google Sheets in which I tried this one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HtoR6Y41uc3xSvfT8KTgD7-YiULct_s_SH77Zi54JiQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Again, this is not a perfect solution. For better results, consider writing a script to automate the process.

Comment: You are right, it will be much efficient and robust to use Scripts. The quick solution will increase B1 whenever any change made in any cell, that will be a problem.  Anyway, thanks for your help, I will need to look for Scripts solution.

Comment: Have you checked tools like UiPath? It's much easier than scripts and it's exponentially powerful.